# isc-dhcp-server randomly stopped working and won't start again

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I've been running isc-dhcp-server on Ubuntu 12 for a few months.  This morning it stopped issuing IP addresses (no configuration changes from when it was working).

I had local IT reboot the box before coming in to investigate.  When I check services, I see:

```
[ - ] isc-dhcp-server
```

when checking its status:

```
isc-dhcp-server stop/waiting
```

when i try and start it:

```
isc-dhcp-server start/running, process 1576
```

then check status again:

```
isc-dhcp-server stop/waiting
```

any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I just found this in syslog:  /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases: file too long to buffer.  File is over 2 gig and contains experations from October 2015.  Should  it not auto remove these?  Question , can i just rm the file and start over?  how do I stop this from happening again?

Comment: You could always back up the file, then create a blank one.  `mv dhcpd.leases dhcpd.leases.bak` then `touch dhcpd.leases`.  It needs at least a blank leases file to even start.

Comment: It does not autoremove. It tries to re-use ip addresses if possible. Yes, you can delete it, but you need to re-start everything on the network (meaning get new leases).